# In bitcoin-cli getpeerinf call what does "-1" mean as a "synced_headers" or "synced_blocks" value?

Tags: bitcoin-core, client, bitcoin-cli, cli, c

Sometimes I see this in getpeerinfo:

"synced_headers": -1,
"synced_blocks": -1,

sometimes it's only synced blocks at -1.

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

It means you either have no headers, no block, or both *known to be* (*) in common with this peer.

From the `help`:

```
$ bitcoin-cli help getpeerinfo
....
    "synced_headers" : n,          (numeric) The last header we have in common with this peer
    "synced_blocks" : n,           (numeric) The last block we have in common with this peer
```

(*) As Pieter cleared in the comment it doesn't mean you aren't on the same chain, just that the peer didn't announce any block to you yet.

Comment: Yes I saw that help but are you sure of the meaning of -1? How is that possible that I have no block in common with so many peers, this -1 is not rare I see this all the time.

Comment: It's possible because they haven't announced any blocks to you yet. It doesn't mean "no blocks in common", it means "no blocks _known_ to be in common".

Comment: Ah ok thanks for your reply MR Wuillle. And why they didn't announce any block? What can prevent a node from announcing its blocks?